# I want to keep an actionbar for all activities

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an actionbar which has a title and few buttons. I want to display this actionbar for all activities. So, instead of including layout code of this actionbar for all screens, how can I use it efficiently ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a BaseActivity(which extends Activity), where you can write this code just once. And then all other activities of your code must extend this BaseActivity. Also in your xml layout, create a separate layout file for this Actionbar, and then reuse this file using the include tag. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: But, click events are different for different activities, How to do that ?

Comment: You can always override the click events of objects declared in the base class. Please go through the concepts of inheritance in java, and i am sure you can easily do that.

Comment: dude, I wasn't worried about inheritance, but if I do something in one activity inside onClick, should it affect the other activity because IDs of the views of the actionbar remain same for all activities. Anyway, I will try and see...

Comment: To be specific, your base class remains same, but that does not mean that new objects arent created. Everytime you move over to a new activity, your base properties are inherited in this new object, and hence you never worry about their ids being the same (because it is a new object!!!). Isnt this basic inheritance? Anyways, if you get stuck somewhere, just add a comment.